# cross-browser async uploader?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Anyone looked into this recently?

12 months ago i was using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

6 months ago i switched to [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) which was the best i could find,

what are people's thoughts, is Plupload still the best uploader for multibrowser async image uploads?

I'm about to start a new site...

Comment: do you know the SWFUpload? http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/multiinstancedemo/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best I found:

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Seems much better than Plupload purely in that it isn't too ambitious. Seems lightweight and easy to use...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the SWFUpload can help you http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/multiinstancedemo/index.php